# Citation style for an edited transcript of a lecture published in a journal

Tags: citation-style

If an edited transcript of a lecture which was given is published in a journal, should the citation style for the transcript be the same as for a paper published as part of conference proceedings? (Thanks Anonymous_M for clarification.)
See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZlaj.png) for example.

Comment: Exactly! Sorry for the ambiguity. As I'm using Zotero as my reference management application, the only suitable 'item type' can be either 'Conference paper' or ‘Journal article'. Therefore the question.

Comment: How did others cite this item? I would look for something authoritative, like the Cambridge Companion to Leo Strauss, https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-companion-to-leo-strauss/to-spare-the-vanquished-and-crush-the-arrogant-leo-strausss-lecture-on-german-nihilism/05D7FA12B317E185CD3EA2B00A20BD32

Answer (score 1):

Look up the Information for Authors of the journal. Normally they specify how they want citations.

Comment: Seems unlikely that they cover this special case.

Answer (score 0):

For the journal, use the journal item type in Zotero (since you're using Zotero). Select the appropriate reference style required by the journal (information for authors).

For the transcript, follow the guide provided by the journal as well.

For a more technical solution, you might want to engage the Zotero forum.

[Possibly out of scope of Academia]
Zotero has a 'catch all' field in all item type: '**Extra**'
Make good use of it as much as it's practicable.

The following Zotero forums might give you a pointer - *transcript of a lecture*

- https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/103076/
- [https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/93801/how-to-cite-lectures-in-the-ieee-citation-style-using-zotero#:~:text=%60Author.,lecture%20%5BType%20of%20Medium%5D](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/93801/how-to-cite-lectures-in-the-ieee-citation-style-using-zotero#:%7E:text=%60Author.,lecture%20%5BType%20of%20Medium%5D).
- https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/item_types_and_fields